# How to play a custom MP3 when I push to GitHub from the command line?

Tags: git, command-line, audio

I have looked on making custom things happen with Automator and such but I can't find a way to link sound effects to CLI commands.

I would like a sound effect to play when I am at the command line and type

```
git push
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Google for `git pre-push hook`

Comment: That seemed like a pre tester tl;dr . but I will look over it some more. Im not sure how to run a script from the command line that will play an audio sound,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the following short script in a file. I called mine “pushit”. Make sure it’s executable and put it in a directory that is in your $PATH.

```
"#!/bin/bash"

git push origin
open spotify:track:0GugYsbXWlfLOgsmtsdxzg
```

Alternatively, you can put the following line in your ~/.profile:

```
alias pushit="git push origin; open spotify:track:0GugYsbXWlfLOgsmtsdxzg;"
```

And remember to:

```
source ~/.profile
```

You should check out this link, answers the question:

http://valeriecoffman.com/git-push-it-good-salt-n-pepa/

Answer (score 1):

You can use quicktime to snip your mp3 and the native mac command line player to play it from command line.

Please see below.

```
#!/bin/bash

## ADD VARIABLES HERE ##
_yourSoundFileAndPath="/Users/jeremykenedy/Desktop/pushit-jk-master/pushit8s.m4a"

## ADD ALIAS'S HERE ##
alias pushitmaster="git push origin master;afplay "$_yourSoundFileAndPath
```

I also created a repo @ https://github.com/jeremykenedy/pushit

Yay !

Jeremy :)